# Role of Resistor at the output of a comparator

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistors, comparator

What is the role of `R1` at the output of this comparator?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fW28DB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

A lot of comparators just have an open-collector output and this is normally used by connecting a pull-up resistor to a positive supply rail. In your circuit you have shown a TL081 (written since the op edited it to an LM311) and this doesn't qualify as a comparator - it's an op-amp and as such, it doesn't need a pull-up resistor.

Here's a circuit of a typical comparator, the LM339: -

[image]

It wouldn't work without a pull-up resistor or something to supply current to the output like an LED: -

[image]

Comment: It's the LM311, I have updated the circuit

Comment: And I have changed my answer to reflect that.